# How to get image source from HTML to PHP?

Tags: php, html, mysql, wordpress, cpanel

I want to get image source from user uploaded image and save it to my sql table. 
I am using a Wordpress site and the Ultimate Member plugin. Uploaded images are saved in `public_html/wp-content/uploads/ultimatemember`, but I need image source, so that an admin can view the image in a browser.

What I would like to do is to get the image source and save it to my sql table. 
I got an image source in HTML and jQuery with the following code:

```
<div hidden id="image_1"></div>    
<div hidden id="image_2"></div>

<script>
    var $ = jQuery;
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var passport_url = $('img[alt="I_1"]').attr("src");
        document.getElementById("image_1").innerHTML = image_1_url;
        var proof_url = $('img[alt="I_2"]').attr("src");
        document.getElementById("image_2").innerHTML = image_2_url;
    });

</script>
```

I want to write PHP code that gets content of `<div id="image_1>"` and `<div id="image_2>"` and saves it to mysql table. I know how to save the path to the sql table, I just don't know how to get the div content in PHP from HTML. What is the proper way to do it?

Comment: You're looking for `AJAX` to post from the front-end to PHP, though you could also simply scrape the filenames from the directory with PHP itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why you're trying saving data using manually created script. 
Because in wordpress you can easily save meta data (that can be image src) using `add_user_meta();`

```
<?php add_user_meta( $user_id, $meta_key, $meta_value, $unique ); ?>
```

You don't even need to add src using `js/innerHtml` (as I don't think you want to save src using `AJAX`)

**As you asked a proper way**

So, I suggest you,

- create a simple form
- submit hidden feilds ie 'src'
- use $_POST, and save data using `add_user_meta();`

Full article for [add_user_meta](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_user_meta)

Thanks